# Unlock file locked by another user in Team Foundation Service (tfs.visualstudio.com)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How can I unlock a file locked by another TFS user when using Team Foundation Service (http://tfs.visualstudio.com)?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a tool:
http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2012

TFS Sidekicks 2012 just did the task